# Python 3.10.10 extracting filename from fullpath, not working with Path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

Using `Python 3.10.10` I want to extract file name from fullpath, using `Path` from `pathlib` module.

From below code, I expect to get `test.pdf` name, but this code prints full pathname

```
from pathlib import Path
Path(r"C:\Users\work\test.pdf").name
```

> 'C:\Users\work\test.pdf'

May I know why it's not giving the filename from above path? How to get the file from full path name?

Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you on? That's the expected result on Linux, it doesn't use Windows filename parsing rules.

Comment: Works fine for me with 3.10.9 on Windows 10.

Comment: I was trying this on `Linux` OS.  I will use my application in Windows and Linux OS.  looks like I need to check the OS type to extract the filename.

Comment: @sfgroups I wonder if you changed your path slashes to / if it would work on Linux - it does on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Path()` function parses filenames according to the current operating system. If you're on Unix and want to process Windows paths, you need to use the [`PureWindowsPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PureWindowsPath) subclass directly.

```
>>> from pathlib import PureWindowsPath
>>> PureWindowsPath(r"C:\Users\work\test.pdf").name
'test.pdf'
```